# Is there truly no way to get information about medical application status?

Tags: medical, faa-approval

I had an event in 2005 that has not happened in the 10 years since.  When I went for a 3rd class medical the AME I went to seemed very skittish and wanted to send my records to Oklahoma City for review.  They received them the first week in March.

As we near the two month mark I have called and asked for a status once each week and have been struck by how little information they provide.  My application, for example, has been in the "handed over to the Doctors" status for almost a month with no new notations on the file.  This means I can't tell if it is sitting in the queue waiting to be processed, or is actually being processed by a Doctor who just isn't putting any notations in.  If I'm in the queue I have no way of knowing whether there are two or two hundred apps in front of mine.  In short, calling and checking the status is a worthless exercise.

In every organization I've ever dealt with there was always some way of going up the chain and getting some kind of information.  I'm told by the call center reps that is not possible.  I wanted to verify that information with the community here, though... is this just the way things are?  Is there no way whatsoever to get some useful information?  If anyone has been down this road and has tips they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you been in touch with AOPA's medical people?

Comment: @casey, I only recently joined the AOPA as a student pilot so I wasn't completely aware of all the services they provide but this is a great suggestion.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dealing with the FAA medical is always a tiring process. Best places to consult would be services like AOPA medical assistance, or through [Aviation Medical Advisory Service (AMAS)](https://www.aviationmedicine.com/).

There are other options probably, but I know AMAS is the go to consulting group for controllers and a lot of airline pilots. AMAS will often help guide you with knowing ahead of time what information you need and what forms to have filled out to try and make the process go quickly.