# Is there any way I can check the status of my medical?

Tags: medical

I was deferred my third class medical because of a certain condition and the doctor said I’ll hear from the FAA in about 3-4 weeks with either my certificate  or they’ll ask for more information.  It’s been 3 weeks going on 4th week, and I’ve heard of them taking 2 months or longer so I was just wondering is there any way I could check the status of my medical like it can tell me it’s been sent back or is currently being reviewed or etc?

Comment: On the off chance that anyone is thinking of closing this: This is *not* a duplicate of [https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15176/is-there-truly-no-way-to-get-information-about-medical-application-status](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15176/is-there-truly-no-way-to-get-information-about-medical-application-status), because nowhere on that page does anyone say how to check the status of your medical application (and that information would not be appropriate as an answer to that question).

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to check the status of your medical application is to call the [Aerospace Medical Certification Division](https://www.faa.gov/other_visit/aviation_industry/designees_delegations/designee_types/ame/amcs/phonenumbers/) at (405) 954-4821.

When you call, it's very likely that you will hear a recorded message saying that due to high call volumes, they are unable to assist you. If you do, call again later. When I was checking on the status of my own application, I had to call quite a few times before my call was finally answered.