# How long does it take to issue an FAA medical certificate?

Tags: faa, medical

How long does it take for the FAA to issue a medical certificate? Exam was 7/23 and haven’t heard anything since.

Comment: Normally when you leave the examiner’s office you take a signed medical certificate with you. If that didn’t happen then the AME should have told you that there was a problem that needed to be resolved by the folks in Oklahoma City. Did the AME mention anything about a deferral? Could you provide more information so we can answer your question?

Comment: @JScarry AME did not mention a problem, said that we would receive a letter for every step of the process but we have not received anything. No mention of a deferral at all.

Comment: Call your AME and ask. What you describe is entirely outside of the realm of normal experience.

Comment: I feel like I have seen a similar question recently...

Comment: @dalearn [This one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/67345/62)?

Comment: @Pondlife yes.  While related, it’s definitely not a duplicate though like I thought it might be.